# Animate tag in svg doesn't trigger animation like expected

Tags: html, xml, animation, svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to animate an svg path for about 3 days now..

When i use the `<animate>` tag, the transition happens however it does so without any animation just from position A to position B.

I'd like to have a transition in between both so that is appears smoothly. What should I do ?

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 167 1888.69">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #f2f2f2;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #65bec0;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: #88d3cd;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        fill: #60b9bc;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="glass" class="cls-1" d="M927.2,52.82c16.15,0,30.77,5.53,41.37,14.51s17.13,21.38,17.13,35.08l.3,1620.4c0,27.38-26.19,49.6-58.49,49.6-16.15,0-30.77-5.53-41.37-14.51S869,1736.52,869,1722.83l-.3-1620.4C868.71,75,894.9,52.83,927.2,52.82Z" transform="translate(-819 -52.82)"/>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M881.46,1086.43h.09l-.09.06Z" transform="translate(-819 -52.82)"/>
  <path id="back-liquid" class="cls-3" d="M925.15,1767.18c27.63.11,50.13-21.59,50.23-48.44L977,1285.27l.51-294.54s-26.11-2.52-49.22-16.49c-12.79-7.73-48.11,12.32-55.73,15.79l3.75,449.17,0,289.36a48.12,48.12,0,0,0,13.45,24.25A50.6,50.6,0,0,0,925.15,1767.18Z" transform="translate(-819 -52.82)"/>



  <g id="front-liquid">
    <path class="cls-4"  transform="translate(-819 -52.82)">
      <animate
        id="poi_front_1"
        attributeName="d"
        values="M929.78,1765.31c-29.07.12-52.74-21.56-52.87-48.42l-2-433.46-.74-294.54s28.27,1.81,51-14.37c14.77-10.5,47,4.34,53.86,15.48l1.87,447.29.17,289.36A47.56,47.56,0,0,1,967,1750.91,54.74,54.74,0,0,1,929.78,1765.31Z;
        m 929.78,1765.31 c -29.07,0.12 -52.74,-21.56 -52.87,-48.42 l -2,-433.46 -2.35,-293.4 c 0,0 29.04531,-29.79622 50.10593,-17.59673 31.46382,10.78462 34.47963,16.02568 55.52938,6.71575 L 980.9,1437.29 l 0.17,289.36 c -2.14495,9.3171 -7.04817,17.7714 -14.07,24.26 -10.15255,9.3127 -23.4433,14.4547 -37.22,14.4Z"
        begin="0s; poi_front_2.end"
        dur="1s"
        />
      <animate
        id="poi_front_2"
        attributeName="d"
        values="m 929.78,1765.31 c -29.07,0.12 -52.74,-21.56 -52.87,-48.42 l -2,-433.46 -2.35,-293.4 c 0,0 29.04531,-29.79622 50.10593,-17.59673 31.46382,10.78462 34.47963,16.02568 55.52938,6.71575 L 980.9,1437.29 l 0.17,289.36 c -2.14495,9.3171 -7.04817,17.7714 -14.07,24.26 -10.15255,9.3127 -23.4433,14.4547 -37.22,14.4 z;
         M929.78,1765.31c-29.07.12-52.74-21.56-52.87-48.42l-2-433.46-.74-294.54s28.27,1.81,51-14.37c14.77-10.5,47,4.34,53.86,15.48l1.87,447.29.17,289.36A47.56,47.56,0,0,1,967,1750.91,54.74,54.74,0,0,1,929.78,1765.31Z"
        begin="poi_front_1.end"
        dur="1.5s"
        />
      </path>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

```css
html,body {width:100%; height:100%;}
.container{
 width: 80%;
height: 80vh;
 margin:auto;
}
svg {
width: 60%;
height:80vh;
margin: auto;
}
```

Here is a codepen demo of my svg : https://codepen.io/knudsem/pen/oNxoxrB

edit: i tried to reorganize the values, but still no luck. I don't get it, what am I missing?

Comment: The values for the animation need to have the same number of commands and the same commands

Comment: hello, what do you mean ? both animation tags has to have the same value?

Comment: commands are the letters i.e. M C etc. There must match in the various values.

Comment: Can it be because of the spacing in the values. Because it looks to me there are the same. Just a differenr order in between animation 1 and animation 2

Comment: Look again, they aren't the same.

Comment: So wait just to be clear, it should be : <animate1   values=' xSetofstring1  ;  xSetofstring2" />         <animate2  values=' xSetofstring2  ;  xSetofstring1" />           ?

Comment: You must read the string inside one `values` attribute letter for letter, and number for number. If there is a letter in the string part before the semicolon, there must be the same letter in the string part after the semicolon. If there is a number, there must be a number. The complete sequence of letters and numbers must match before and after the semicolon. The comparison to the other `<animate>` tag is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe tomarrow morning i'll have more luck after reading you again, because for now i'm not getting it.  So you're saying :  <animate1 values=' xSetofstring1 ; xSetofstring1" />  ??    But then aren't you telling it to animate from x position to the same x position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two observations:

You don't need 2 animations. You can use instead a list of 3 values for the animation: values ="v1;v2;v1" This together with `repeatCount="indefinite"` will do the trick.

Secondly: in this case the paths should be identical except the C and the S command in the middle. You need to keep the same commands in the same order, changing only the y value for the control points of the curves.

Also since I've changed the d attribute manually I've transformed it to all absolute using this converter: https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv

```html
<svg viewBox="0 850 167 1888.69">

  <g id="front-liquid">

    <path transform="translate(-819 -52.82)" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="
             M929.78,1765.31
             C900.71,1765.43,877.04,1743.75,876.91,1716.89
             L874.91,990.03
                         
             C872.5,990 901.6,950.2,922.7,972.4
             S957.1,988.4,978.2,979.1

             L980.9,1726.65
             C978.925,1735.9671,974.022,1744.42,967,1750.91
             C956.847,1760.2227,943.56,1765.3647,929.78,1765.31 Z">

      <animate attributeName="d" values="M929.78,1765.31
             C900.71,1765.43,877.04,1743.75,876.91,1716.89
             L874.91,990.03
             
             C872.5,990  901.6,988.2   922.7,972.4
             S957.1,960  978.2,979.1
             
             L980.9,1726.65
             C978.925,1735.9671,974.022,1744.42,967,1750.91
             C956.847,1760.2227,943.56,1765.3647,929.78,1765.31 Z;


M929.78,1765.31
             C900.71,1765.43,877.04,1743.75,876.91,1716.89
             L874.91,990.03
                         
             C872.5,990 901.6,950.2,922.7,972.4
             S957.1,988.4,978.2,979.1

             L980.9,1726.65
             C978.925,1735.9671,974.022,1744.42,967,1750.91
             C956.847,1760.2227,943.56,1765.3647,929.78,1765.31 Z;


M929.78,1765.31
             C900.71,1765.43,877.04,1743.75,876.91,1716.89
             L874.91,990.03

             C872.5,990  901.6,988.2   922.7,972.4
             S957.1,960  978.2,979.1

             L980.9,1726.65
             C978.925,1735.9671,974.022,1744.42,967,1750.91
             C956.847,1760.2227,943.56,1765.3647,929.78,1765.31 Z" begin="0s;" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />

    </path>

  </g>

</svg>
```

I've removed the non animated paths and I've changed the viewBox value so that I'd be able to see the relevant part of the shape. You can change back to what you had,

Comment: Hi, first of all  thank you so much for your answer, it is amazing and very well detailed, i will accept your answer as soon as i manage to do it on codepen <3 I just have a little question , why would you need the value to be defined in the path tag ? After the tutorial i watched, the guys deleted it and put everything in the animate. Also i don't understand why you would define 3 times the same path value in the animate ? How can it knows to go from animation A to animation B if the values are the same ?

Comment: You don't need to define the d attribute of the path if you don't want to. However if the SMIL animations are not supported, if you are using a d attribute you'll be able to see something. You don't have to. As for your second question: you are using 2 animations: one to animate from value1 to value2 and another to animate from value2 to value1. Instead I'm using only one animation with a list of 3 values. I think is shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Ok cool thanks :) but why did you decide to change the line with the C and the S, why are those lines specials and can be changed but all the other can't ? the numbers in the C and S represent the Y value of what i understood in your explanation, however a Y value alone  shouldn't be enough to animate something no ?

Comment: This is the only part that is changing during the animation. Please try drawing this: `<svg viewBox="870 960 150 50">
<path stroke="red" fill="none" d="M874.91,990.03 C872.5,990  901.6,988.2   922.7,972.4 S957.1,960  978.2,979.1" /></svg>`

Comment: I think I start to get it. Though as you look like you really know the subject. Would you have a link to a good tutorial about the explanation behind the numbers and the letters for svg path, d value etc.. ? Much appreciate the help thanks mate

Comment: This is an MDN article about the path commands: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221037/discussion-between-mathi-and-enxaneta).